Trouble accessing api endpoints in vercel
I have successfully deployed my api from laravel and it's stable but I can only access this index.php file I created from the examples I found on the internet. On postman it isn't how I thought it'd be, like the URL for the root directory. I'd like to know how to set up the deploy to access specifically the routes/api folder where the api routes are defined (I've created this api only to be used for another aplication so I only care about the data endpoints).
Have a look at how the vercel.json looks like. I believe is here where a should change stuff so it isn't just that index page showing:
{
    "version": 2,
      "framework": null,
    "functions": {
        "api/index.php": { "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0" }
    },
    "routes": [{
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/api/index.php"
    }],
    "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "production",
        "APP_DEBUG": "true",
        "APP_URL": "https://yourproductionurl.com",
 
        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",
 
        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie"
    }
    
}

Perhaps is something in vercel configurations, but I haven't found anything on the docs. Any help would be wounderful.

Which version of laravel you are deploying?

To fix this issue, simply update your URL from https://yourprojecturl/api/ to https://yourprojecturl/api/api/.
